# .net transaction scope block second transaction

Tags: c#, .net, database, transactions, transactionscope

In my application I have the following pattern:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    Function1();
    Function2();
    Function3();
}
```

My problen is that Function2 calls another function that connects to another DB ... and the transaction becomes distributed and I get an exception.

Is there any way in the code in which I can make a db call that is not part of the current transaction? My code in Function2 does just a read ... so I don't want to be part of current transaction.

Thanks, Radu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Around `function2` you could create a new transaction with `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`, thus forcing it into its own separate transaction. Since only one resource (the other database) will be used in that transaction is shouldn't become distributed.

Comment: and if I create the second transaction scope as TransactionScope.Suppress Do I lost the parent transaction?

Comment: @RaduD Only within the scope of the transaction scope I expect (but I would want to test to confirm this).